Extraction of language tags from PDF paragraphs / Text Containers
I am trying to extract language tags from PDF paragraphs in Python 3.9.
What I need:
I need to check if all language tags are the same in the entire pdf file, with pdfminer library I was able to extract some properties like font, size, colour and coordinates of this LTTextBoxHorizonal object but after mining in object locals I still cannot find part related to language tag. I know how to get it for the file itself but it won't detect it for every container in a file. I wonder how Adobe Acrobat gets information about it and how to get there.
Here I found some information about localization  settings, but I still cannot find corresponding data in an object. Does anyone know how to get access to this property?
The article about PDF which I studied for this - explaining the structure of PDF
This is how I analysed containers in PDF:
  from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages, extract_text
  from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar, LTRect, LTFigure 
   
   def extract_paragraph_metadata(pdf_path):
    for pagenum, page in enumerate(extract_pages(pdf_path)):
        for element in page:
            #if element is text
            if isinstance(element,LTTextContainer):
               # Function to extract text from the text block
                d = element.analyze
                print(d) 



See ISO 32000-2 Section 14.9.2. From a quick read, Natural Language appears to be an inherited attribute - i.e it will only be specified locally if different from the parent:
"The natural language used for content in a document shall be determined in a hierarchical fashion,
based on whether an optional Lang entry (PDF 1.4) is present in any of several possible locations. At
the highest level, the document’s default language (which applies to both text strings and text within
content streams) may be specified by a Lang entry in the document catalog dictionary (see 7.7.2,
"Document catalog dictionary"). This applies to both content within content streams and any text
strings, including text strings not included in the structure hierarchy such as, for example, entries in
metadata, outline entries and names for optional content groups. Below this, the language may be
specified for the following items:"
(This paragraph is followed by a list of places Natural Language may be specified, and thus over-riden. Unless PDFMiner supports this stuff, it seems it will be complex.)
